# How to Use F# ODATA TypeProvider with OAuth authorization

Tags: f#

I have a OData svc that needs Oauth token for authorization. The metadata url is available [here](https://wamsstageclus001rest-hs.cloudapp-int.net/API/%24metadata?api-version=1.0).

However,

```
let MySvc = ODataService<"https://wamsstageclus001rest-hs.cloudapp-int.net/API/$metadata?api-version=1.0">
```

returns error `reading schema, 404`.

What am I missing? How can I use the API ?

Comment: Does doing `OdataServuce<@"https://.....">` work? this should stop the compiler interpreting escape sequences

Comment: Try using `%24metadata` instead of `$metadata` -- URL encoding 101.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in the FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll that ships with VS2012 regarding how to append `$metadata` to the URL.

Fortunately, type providers are 'just another library' needed at design-time, so to address this bug (and some other type provider issues), our current plans are to release an updated type provider library out-of-band.  Historically with VS2010 the F# team has done open-source release updates of the F# compiler/library sources and powerpack a month or two after VS ships, and so if one assumes the same for VS2012, this would likely be a possible time for us to publish some updates to type providers.  (I can't give any more release schedule information at this time.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is the correct URL to use. Typically you provide the URL for the service, and the service provider looks up the metadata on its own. However your code is providing the URL for the metadata.

Because of this, the type provider is probably adding additional information to the URL in order to utilize it, and the service does not know what to do with these compound URLs.

EDIT: Apparently someone felt I was not clear.

```
https://wamsstageclus001rest-hs.cloudapp-int.net/API/$metadata?api-version=1.0
```

Will become, when the ODataAdapter attempts to obtain metadata information

```
https://wamsstageclus001rest-hs.cloudapp-int.net/API/$metadata?api-version=1.0$metadata
```

Or something similar. If you browse to that particular site, you will see a 404 error.

However if you give the ODataAdapter

```
https://wamsstageclus001rest-hs.cloudapp-int.net/API/
```

Then adding the metadata won't cause a 404 error. You should be able to leave the version information, since it is using a URL class instead of string manipulation (or so I would hope) which would look like the following

```
    https://wamsstageclus001rest-hs.cloudapp-int.net/API/?api-version=1.0
```